# ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length. While implementing RSA with python

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, pycrypto

I am trying to implement RSA in python to encrypt and then decrypt the text given in a file.

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA as rsa
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import binascii

def encrypt(message, pukey):
    pukey = rsa.import_key(pukey)
    encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pukey)
    encmessage = encryptor.encrypt(message)
    encmessage = binascii.hexlify(encmessage)
    return encmessage

def decrypt(message, prkey):
    prkey = rsa.import_key(prkey)
    decryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(prkey)
    decmessage = decryptor.decrypt(message)
    return decmessage

def main():
    keypair = rsa.generate(1024)
    with open('abcd.txt', 'r') as f:
        mes = f.read().encode()
    pukey = keypair.publickey().exportKey()
    prkey = keypair.exportKey()
    enc = encrypt(mes, pukey)
    print(enc)
    dec = decrypt(enc, prkey)
    print(dec)
    input('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the content of 'abcd.txt':

```
abcdef
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
b'a53fd1fca73b07d5b18d77d4c95a8e40e002a34b53fcbbc3e1f7277721a7c2fa74be9a83cf6f273fcb98a6124905a40d8e6b34bc781ffdff7a09a68bdadf2eb5c5d4c56756c1249828dcb113fed832e7e5f50cd613f1d4458e8ebbc0d5f856669f9929cb8b70371ba657a74d1d41022c512a80c1d5ce492b852328de42be76e4'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\STUDY\VIT MATERIAL\Semester 04\08 Project exhibition\Material\Temp_project\cryptRSA1.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:\STUDY\VIT MATERIAL\Semester 04\08 Project exhibition\Material\Temp_project\cryptRSA1.py", line 34, in main    
    dec = decrypt(enc, prkey)
  File "d:\STUDY\VIT MATERIAL\Semester 04\08 Project exhibition\Material\Temp_project\cryptRSA1.py", line 23, in decrypt
    decmessage = decryptor.decrypt(message)
  File "C:\Users\dhruv\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py", line 167, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Ciphertext with incorrect length.")
ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.
```

I am very new to this module and cryptography in general. Please suggest the changes I need to do to make this work.

Comment: When encrypting, you hex encode the ciphertext, but do not perform a hex decoding when decrypting.

Comment: @Topaco Seems like an easy fix. Please add the code I need to replace my code with?

Comment: Just add the following line to the beginning of the `decrypt()` method: `message = binascii.unhexlify(message)`